# Creating Dynamic JLabels for sort of a messenger app using Java

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

So I am trying to make a messenger sort of app with Java Drag and Drop in Netbeans.
 I am fairly new at it. I initially want to take a string from the text area and display it in a JLabel in another panel. I tried to do it in the following process but it did not work.Can someone please help?

```
    private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    int i=0;
    message = messageType.getText();
    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel();
    messageLabel.setText(message);
    messageLabel.setSize(100, 100);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentY(0);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    clientPanel.add(messageLabel);
    messageLabel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have no idea what layout manager clientPanel is using and so do not know how well it will accept a JLabel being dropped into it, so as asked your direct question is unanswerable, other than to say you should always call `revalidate()` on a container (clientPanel) and then `repaint()` after adding or removing components so that the container re-lays out its components and then redraws them.

I advise against creating new JLabels for this. Much easier to set up the GUI including all necessary JLabels from the very beginning, give them text, empty spaces if need be, and then during the program set the text of an existing JLabel.

If on the other hand you wish to show multiple messages on the cientPanel, then consider using a `JList<String>` or a non-focusable JTextArea.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have called the functions that you have mentioned and it is working now. I was also thinking about what will happen if I try to send a larger message, it should not work if I try to fit it in a label. So the JTextArea will work there I guess. I just tried your suggestion for the label, hope it will work for JTextAreas as well

Comment: @TheNoob: for a JTextArea, make it non-focusable by calling `.setFocusable(false)` so it can't be edited by the user. Also consider calling `.append(String text)` on it if you want to add text to its end. If you want it to automatically wrap text, there are methods available for this too.

Comment: I am trying to use the TextArea now and I have used the setEditable() to false. Also, I have replaced the setBounds method with two other methods, setAllignmentX() and setAllignmentY() but the JTextArea isn't coming on my screen. To wrap a text in it, I have used the setText() method.